# Is there a simple proof of every Borel subalgebra containing a Cartan subalgebra is standard?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, root-systems

If a Borel subalgebra $\mathfrak b$ of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ contains a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak h$, then we have a root space decomposition
$$
\mathfrak b = \mathfrak h \oplus \left(\oplus_{\alpha \in S} \mathfrak g_{\alpha}\right)
$$
with $S$ being some subset of the set $R$ of roots of $\mathfrak g$.
The fact that $\mathfrak b$ is solvable already asserts that $S$ cannot contain both $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ for any $\alpha \in R$.

> From this, can we conclude that $S = R^+$ with respect to some basis of $R$?

Humphreys (Chapter 16) states this result as a consequence of the conjugacy of the Cartan subalgebras and the Borel subalgebras, but it feels like this should be a standalone result that can be concluded from basic properties of root systems and the fact that the Borel subalgebras are maximally solvable.

Comment: If we already know that the Borel subalgebra has a root decomposition I think we can probably make an argument via Lie's Theorem that it would have to be positive roots for some choice of ordering. However, I think Humphreys is using this conjugacy to show that it has such a root decomposition in the first place and moreover that the Borel subalgebra is standard for any Cartan subalgebra it contains. He doesn't claim they have a root decomposition before this.

Comment: @Callum Right, I was just wondering if one could arrive at some of these conclusions in Humphrey's book in a simpler way... Which often seems to be the case! How do you envision using Lie's theorem, though? I was actually thinking more along the lines of using the simple reflections to control the signs of the roots.

Comment: If we accept that it has such a root decomposition, then one can use the fact about root systems that any subset $S$ that is closed ($\alpha, \beta \in S, \alpha+\beta \in R \implies \alpha +\beta \in S$) and such that $S \cap -S =\emptyset$ is contained in a set of positive roots $P$ w.r.t. some ordering. (This is e.g. prop. 22 in Bourbaki's Lie volume, VI 1.7). Your set $S$ is closed because $\mathfrak b$ is a subalgebra. Now if $S$ is not the full set of positive roots $P$, the one with $S=P$ is a strictly bigger, solvable subalgebra containing the same $\mathfrak h$.

Comment: @user494572 My idea with Lie's Theorem is that it says any solvable Lie algebra stabilises a flag in any representation. Take the adjoint representation. I believe we can see that each subspace in the flag is spanned by root spaces plus $\mathfrak{h}$ which gives some ordering on the roots. Well, it gives a preorder but I think we can massage this into the partial order we want. I haven't worked out that last part which depends on the flag being "full enough" in some sense. It is somewhat moot though as I think Torsten's answer gives you the exact answer you are looking for.